# can i make a volume on GKE (with autopilot) that can use ReadWritemany?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, volumes, mounted-volumes

I'm currently trying to create a GKE cluster and would like to be able to scale my PostgreSQL pods beyond 1 active instance but I'm getting stuck on the read-write permission of my volume is there a way to get readwritemany to work in GKE autopilot?
a hot spare for my PostgreSQL pod would also be helpful if that is possible.
thank you for the advice in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC you're unable to use Google's (Compute Engine's) Persistent Disks as `ReadWriteMany`. This may be documented on [`cloud.google.com`](https://cloud.google.com)  but I was unable to find it.

See Kubernetes' documentation for [Access Modes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes) and specifically `GCEPersistentDisk`. These support `ReadWriteOnce` and `ReadOnlyMany` but **not** `ReadWriteMany`.

There may be other ways but, one (Goole-supported) way you can get `ReadWriteMany` on GCP is to use Filestore. See [Using the Filestore CSI driver](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/filestore-csi-driver).

For completeness (!) another way would be to use a PostgreSQL service such as [Cloud SQL for PostgreSQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/features#postgres)

Answer (score 2):

Compute engine persistent disk [does not support](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/persistent-volumes#access_modes) ReadWriteMany access mode.

GKE Autopilot cluster [supports](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/autopilot-overview#container_isolation) StorageType "NFS" and by default installed with Filestore CSI [addon](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/autopilot-overview#comparison). It is important that you **do not** perform nfs mount in your container because Autopilot will reject privileged pod, see [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/filestore-csi-driver#access_a_volume_using_the) for a quick guide how to use it and how much it can [cost](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/pricing) you.

Comment: Thank you a lot for adding the cost that was really helpful :)

Comment: This is just plain stupid :( They "ban" creating self managed NFS share and force you to use Filestore that is minimum 1T and cca 200$ a month... and there is virtually no alternative if you want to have same folder on multiple pods.

Answer (score 0):

Just a service announcement I found [this](https://www.kubegres.io/) library that can set up a leader-follower design pattern in postgreSQL in a container for you. So you can scale your db  instaces.